# Deleting While Iterating in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops

I'm iterating over a very large set of strings, which iterates over a smaller set of strings. Due to the size, this method takes a while to do, so to speed it up, I'm trying to delete the strings from the smaller set that no longer needs to be used as it goes along. Below is my current code:

```
    Ms::Fasta.foreach(@database) do |entry|
        all.each do |set|
            if entry.header[1..40].include? set[1] + "|"
                startVal = entry.sequence.scan_i(set[0])[0]

                if startVal != nil
                    @locations << [set[0], set[1], startVal, startVal + set[1].length]
                    all.delete(set)
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

The problem I face is that the easy way, `array.delete(string)`, effectively adds a break statement to the inner loop, which messes up the results. The only way I know how to fix this is to do this:

```
Ms::Fasta.foreach(@database) do |entry|
        i = 0

        while i < all.length
            set = all[i]

            if entry.header[1..40].include? set[1] + "|"
                startVal = entry.sequence.scan_i(set[0])[0]

                if startVal != nil
                    @locations << [set[0], set[1], startVal, startVal + set[1].length]
                    all.delete_at(i)
                    i -= 1
                end
            end

            i += 1
        end
    end
```

This feels kind of sloppy to me. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: easier way to do what? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: can you please not accept your own answer below? It's clearly not the best one

Answer (score 38, accepted):

use `delete_if`

```
array.delete_if do |v|
    if v.should_be_deleted?
        true
    else
        v.update
        false
    end
end
```

Comment: Funny if :).

`    array.delete_if { |v| v.should_be_deleted? }`

Comment: The if made perfect sense if he wanted to run `v.update` in any elegant manner :)

Comment: FYI, delete is immediate, so if block raises, changes will still be reflected

Comment: Ruby is so much fun

Answer (score -1):

use 'arr.shift'

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
while(a.length!=0)
  print a
  a.shift
  print "\n"
end
```

Output:

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4]
[4]

Comment: this won't work
```
a = [1,2,3,4] 
a.each do 
  puts a.shift
end
1
2
 => [3, 4]
```

Comment: @Ivan thanks for pointing this. Last time I did not tested with each do for array but was sure that shift will do the required job. So edited it now. Check it!

Comment: also, `Array#shift` is inefficient, will cause O(n²) runtime.