# How can I use Array#delete while iterating over the array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration

I have an array that I want to iterate over and delete some of the elements. This doesn't work:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.each do |x|
  next if x < 3
  a.delete x
  # do something with x
end
a #=> [1, 2, 4]
```

I want `a` to be `[1, 2]`. How can I get around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting While Iterating in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933366/deleting-while-iterating-in-ruby)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

`a.delete_if { |x| x >= 3 }`

See method documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_if)

Update:

You can handle x in the block:

```
a.delete_if do |element|
  if element >= 3
    do_something_with(element)
    true # Make sure the if statement returns true, so it gets marked for deletion
  end
end
```

Comment: I need to do something with `x` if it gets deleted. Should I put that in the block?

Comment: @Adrian Or you could use `reject!`.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that `reject!` will return `nil` if no elements were rejected, while `delete_if` returns the original array.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to delete from the array, you can filter it so:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

b = a.select {|x| x < 3}

puts b.inspect # => [1,2]

b.each {|i| puts i} # do something to each here
```

Comment: Sorry to raise a zombie post but curious as to whether the b = a subset of a approach increases memory usage or whether it uses internal pointers or something to refer to the original a items? Reason I ask is my use case is fairly memory sensitive so curious as to whether deleting from the original array or select is a better method...

Comment: @gorlaz `.select` returns a new ruby object which will use more memory.  See this example https://pastebin.com/23e10bKy

Comment: This is also more "functional" in the sense that data is not altered.

Answer (score 5):

I asked this question not long ago.

[Deleting While Iterating in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933366/deleting-while-iterating-in-ruby)

It's not working because Ruby exits the `.each` loop when attempting to delete something. If you simply want to delete things from the array, `delete_if` will work, but if you want more control, the solution I have in that thread works, though it's kind of ugly.

Comment: The deletion doesn't break the loop. `each` effectively iterates by using the index. So if you delete, the indexes are different, and the next iteration will use the new indexes. Try this: `arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; arr.each_with_index {|e,i| p [arr, e, i]; next if e < 3; arr.delete e }`. When item 3 is reached, the index is 2. After 3 is deleted, the next iteration increments index to 3, and the item is 5. So 4 is skipped. 6 is skipped for the same reason.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is using `reject!`, which is arguably clearer since it has a `!` which means "this will change the array". The only difference is that `reject!` will return `nil` if no changes were made.

```
a.delete_if {|x| x >= 3 }
```

or

```
a.reject! {|x| x >= 3 }
```

will both work fine.