# Is it safe to delete from an Array inside each?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Is it possible to safely delete elements from an `Array` while iterating over it via `each`? A first test looks promising:

```
a = (1..4).to_a
a.each { |i| a.delete(i) if i == 2 }
# => [1, 3, 4]
```

However, I could not find hard facts on:

- Whether it is safe (by design)
- Since which Ruby version it is safe

At some points in the past, it seems that it was [not possible to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3260715/968531):

> It's not working because Ruby exits the `.each` loop when attempting to delete something.

The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) does not state anything about deletability during iteration.

I am not looking for `reject` or `delete_if`. I want to do things with the elements of an array, and sometimes also remove an element from the array (after I've done other things with said element).

**Update 1:** I was not very clear on my definition of "safe", what I meant was:

- do not raise any exceptions
- do not skip any element in the `Array`

Comment: It is not safe (depending on how you define "safe") in all languages I have good experience with. Modifying a collection while iterating it is guaranteed to break your program or surprise you. Can't think of a legitimate use case for this.

Comment: to play it safe, iterate a _copy_ of the array, while deleting elements from the original

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not rely on unauthorized answers too much. The answer you cited is wrong, as is pointed out by Kevin's comment to it.

It is safe (from the beginning of Ruby) to delete elements from an Array while `each` in the sense that Ruby will not raise an error for doing that, and will give a decisive (i.e., not random) result.

However, you need to be careful because when you delete an element, the elements following it will be shifted, hence the element that was supposed to be iterated next would be moved to the position of the deleted element, which has been iterated over already, and will be skipped.

Comment: I wanted to challenge what you said, but by adding a `puts i;` into my example code I could verify that indeed the next element is "skipped". That means I will have to duplicate my array and iterate over the copy.

Comment: @NobodysNightmare: "I wanted to challenge what you said" - generally, users with a gold badge for the tag know what they're talking about. :)

Answer (score 3):

In order to answer your question, whether it is "safe" to do so, you will first have to define what you mean by "safe". Do you mean

1. it doesn't crash the runtime?
2. it doesn't `raise` an `Exception`?
3. it *does* `raise` an `Exception`?
4. it behaves deterministically?
5. it does what you expect it to do? (What *do* you expect it to do?)

Unfortunately, the Ruby Language Specification is not exactly helpful:

> ## 15.2.12.5.10 Array#each
>
> ---
>
> `each`(*&block*)
>
> ---
>
> **Visibility**: public
>
> **Behavior**:
>
> - If block is given:
>
>   1. For each element of the receiver in the indexing order, call *block* with the element as the only argument.
>   2. Return the receiver.

This seems to imply that it is indeed completely safe in the sense of 1., 2., 4., and 5. above.

[The documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-each) says:

> ## `each { |item| block }` → `ary`
>
> Calls the given block once for each element in `self`, passing that element as a parameter.

Again, this seems to imply the same thing as the spec.

Unfortunately, *none* of the currently existing Ruby implementations interpret the spec in this way.

What *actually* happens in MRI and YARV is the following: the mutation to the array, including any shifting of the elements and/or indices becomes visible immediately, including to the internal implementation of the iterator code which is based on array indices. So, if you delete an element at or before the position you are currently iterating, you will skip the *next* element, whereas if you delete an element *after* the position you are currently iterating, you will skip *that* element. For `each_with_index`, you will also observe that all elements after the deleted element have their indices shifted (or rather the other way around: the indices stay put, but the elements are shifted).

So, this behavior is "safe" in the sense of 1., 2., and 4.

The other Ruby implementations *mostly* copy this (undocumented) behavior, but being undocumented, you cannot rely on it, and in fact, I believe at least one did experiment briefly with raising some sort of `ConcurrentModificationException` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I was indeed expecting something like 5, my expectation was:
The element would be deleted, but in no case any element is skipped.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it is safe, based on the following:

```
2.2.2 :035 > a = (1..4).to_a
 => [1, 2, 3, 4] 
2.2.2 :036 > a.each { |i| a.delete(i+1) if i > 1 ; puts i }
1
2
4
 => [1, 2, 4]
```

I'd infer from this test that Ruby correctly recognises while iterating through the contents that the element "3" has been deleted while element "2" was being processed, otherwise element "4" would also have been deleted.

However,

```
2.2.2 :040 > a.each { |i| puts i; a.delete(i) if i > 1 ; puts i }
1
1
2
2
4
4
```

This suggests that after "2" is deleted, the next element processed is whichever is now third in the array, so the element that used to be in third place does not get processed at all. each appears to re-examine the array to find the next element to process on every iteration.

I think that with that in mind, you ought to duplicate the array in your circumstances prior to processing.

Comment: As soon as you delete the element you are currently looking at (i.e. `i`, rather than `i+1`), the iteration will skip future elements.
That is why your example code works: You remove a future element, which should (as I learned now) work flawlessly.

Comment: Well it will effectively skip the element that was the next in the array, not all future elements of course. It wil still process the elements that is now in the subsequent position to the current one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

All `.each` does is returns an enumerator, which holds the collection an a pointer to where it left. Example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a.each # => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>
b.next # => 1
a.delete(2)
b.next # => 3
a.clear
b.next # => StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

Each with block calls `next` until the iteration reaches its end. So as long as you don't modify any 'future' array records it should be safe.

However there are so many helpful methods in ruby's `Enumerable` and `Array` you really shouldn't ever need to do this.

Comment: "So as long as you don't modify ... it should be safe" The OP is asking what happens when you **do** modify. Your answer is pointless. And your mentioning the enumerator use of `each` does not seem to be related to the OP's point.

Comment: I simply explained with an example how deleting future records shifts the array, but I guess to each his own

Answer (score 0):

You are right, in the past it was advised not to remove items from the collection while iterating over it. In my tests and at least with version 1.9.3 in practice in an array this gives no problem, even when deleting prior or next elements.

It is my opinion that while you can you shouldn't.
A more clear and safe approach is to reject the elements and assign to a new array.

```
b = a.reject{ |i| i == 2 } #[1, 3, 4]
```

In case you want to reuse your a array that is also possible

```
a = a.reject{ |i| i == 2 } #[1, 3, 4]
```

which is in fact the same as

```
a.reject!{ |i| i == 2 } #[1, 3, 4]
```

You say you don't want to use reject because you want to do other things with the elements before deleting, but that is also possible.

```
a.reject!{ |i| puts i if i == 2;i == 2 } 
# 2
#[1, 3, 4]
```